# Can we send "\" via Sendkeys in Selenium in a textbox?

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I have to send `\` in my username but couldn't able to send it via `sendkeys()` method in `selenium.

Also tried by passing the username from Properties file but `Eclipse` is not sending `\` in the username field.

Username Example: abc\xyz.123

And I have tried :

```
WebDriver driver=null; System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:\\Users\\nitin.chauhan\\Desktop\\Selenium\\IEDriverServer.exe"); 
DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
caps.setCapability( InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS, true); 
driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(caps); 

driver.get("172.16.1.225/IBSv54/login.html");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='UsernameManual']")).sendKeys("FPS\Nitin.‌​Chauhan"));
```

Comment: WebDriver driver=null;
  System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:\\Users\\nitin.chauhan\\Desktop\\Selenium\\IEDriverServer.exe");
  
  DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
  caps.setCapability(
      InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS,
      true);
  
  driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(caps);
  
  
  driver.get("http://172.16.1.225/IBSv54/login.html");
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='UsernameManual']")).sendKeys("FPS\Nitin.Chauhan"));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using an escape character before it like this "abc\\xyz.123"